# What client front-end options can I use to make a Facebook game?

Tags: flash, javascript, html5, facebook

I have been requested to make a port of an iOS game for Facebook.

The game itself is fairly simple, it is a puzzle game using a 2d array for a grid with XML passed from a server for loading objects onto the the grid, to create levels.
The game will ask questions at stages which will be passed to my server and stored for research purposes.

I have looked into both Flash and HTML5/js both of which I have little to no experience in (I'm experienced in Java/C#/Ruby + Rails).

Javascript seems like a nightmare from what I have read, even looking into javascript game engines, but at least it is free.

My backend will most likely be rails for handling server logic.

- Is javascript for programming games really a problem for simple games on Facebook?
- Are js game engines worth using? Does anyone have any experience with them?
- Would prevention of cheating be possible with a js/rails game, do server side checks work?*
- Are there any alternatives for a front end for someone with C#/Java/Ruby background?**

I've never seen any Unity or Java apps on Facebook (I don't use it much) and as this is a research project is for my university, I would like to avoid licensing issues.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As we're a Q&A site, and not a discussion forum, it would be better to narrow down this question to one specific queries, and if you have additional questions, post them separately. You're more likely to get the directed answers you're seeking and you'll improve the quality and searchability of the site.

Comment: "Is javascript for programming games really a problem for simple games on Facebook?"  What does this question mean?

Comment: Also, on unity games in facebook: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5659/unity-on-facebook

Comment: You **can** develop flash games with free software. See this [question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-can-i-develop-flash-games-without-expensive-software).

Comment: Flash vs HTML5 is debated in so many questions, eg. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11019/is-there-a-fundamental-technical-reason-for-flash-being-a-more-popular-game-plat

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this field, but fundamentally any kind of web-based tech can be used to make a facebook game.  As long as you can make the appropriate API calls via some mechanism, and you can put your game in an iframe, you are good to go.

The biggest market is obviously flash games, mainly because it's pretty close to ubiquitous and you don't have to worry as much about cross platform compatibility.

HTML5 games are getting more popular, but that's primarily as there was a push to make games that work on smartphones.

As I linked to in the comments, there are definitely Unity powered games on facebook.

I don't know any Java applet games off hand, but I'm sure it could be done.